# Nodejs Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat

Tags: node.js, nodemailer, email-templates

Sending email with the templates using ejs template for rendering the content 
but facing this issue when send email getting **ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat**

**emailcontroller.js**

```
sendEmail: function (req, res, next) {
    try {
        if (req.body.email) {
            var templateDir = path.join(__dirname, 'template','emailView');
            var temp = new EmailTemplate(templateDir);
            let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
                 host: 'smtp.gmail.com',
                port: 587,
                secure: false, // 
                auth: {
                  user: 'user@gmail.com', // generated ethereal user
                  pass: 'user12345' // generated ethereal password
                },
                tls: {
                    rejectUnauthorized: false
                }
            });
            var locals = {
                username: "User" //dynamic data for bind into the template
            };
            temp.render(locals, function (err, result) {
                if(err)
                console.log("err",err);
                else {
                        let mailOptions = {
                            from: 'user@gmail.com', // sender address
                            to: req.body.email, // list of receivers
                            subject: 'Welcome ✔', // Subject line
                            html:result.html,
                            text:result.text

                        };
                        transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (error, info) => {
                            if (error) {
                                res.status(500).send(JSON.stringify({
                                    "status": "failed",
                                    "statuscode": res.statusCode,
                                    "message": error,
                                    "data": null
                                }));
                            } else {
                                res.status(200).send(JSON.stringify({
                                    "status": 0,
                                    "statuscode": res.statusCode,
                                }));

                            }
                        });
                    }
                })

            }

    } catch (err) {
        res.status(500).send(JSON.stringify({
            "status": 2,
            "statuscode": res.statusCode,
            "message": err.message,
            "data": null
        }));
    }

},
```

My Project structure

```
D:\\xampp\\htdocs\\myproject\\controller\\template
```

in which **emailView.ejs** file under **template** folder

also add in **app.js**

```
app.engine('html',require('ejs').renderFile);
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.set('view engine', 'html');
```

i have found many solution but did not work
1. i removed emailView

```
( eg :var templateDir = path.join(__dirname, 'template');)
```

but in which i got

```
Neither html nor text template files found or are both empty in path template
```

Answer (score 1):

To troubleshoot, I would try placing the template file in the same directory that the code resides in and move it to where it needs to be when you figure out the issue.  No doubt it is a path issue.

Comment: template file is resides in same folder where code is exist ("controller/tepmlate/emailView.ejs ) and code is in controller/emailcontroller.js

Answer (score 0):

It works,i have changed filename to html.ejs and remove  'emailView'
**OLD**

```
  var templateDir = path.join(__dirname, 'template','emailView');
```

**NEW**

```
  var templateDir = path.join(__dirname, 'template');
```